# Dynamically link Windows DLL when no import library is available?

Tags: dll, sdl-2

I am just trying to integrate SDL2_mixer in a small app of mine. SDL2_mixer comes with a bunch of external modules provided as DLLs but with no import libs accompanying them. Now I am wondering how I should (dynamically) link them into my app when I cannot tell the compiler to create the required dynamic link info because I have no way to tell it about the DLL and its interface. Is there a way to accomplish that?

I was even going so far as to download the source code of the required modules (ogg, vorbis, flac, mpg123) to build the dlls myself and get the libs, but mpg123 stopped me dead in the tracks because it is totally porting unfriendly (no up to date make files for Windows, so no config.h etc. header files, hence missing type declarations and what not).

Btw, SDL2_mixer.dll (from the binaries package) doesn't come with an import lib either.

Comment: I don't think you need to link anything other than `SDL2_mixer` itself? Just put the dlls it ships with next to your exe.

Comment: Well, SDL2_mixer.dll doesn't come with an import lib either ...

Comment: Looking at SDL2_mixer-devel-2.0.4-VC.zip.  It's there in (say) lib/x86/SDL2_mixer.lib

Comment: Where exactly did you download SDL2_mixer?

Comment: https://www.libsdl.org/projects/SDL_mixer/release/SDL2_mixer-2.0.4-win32-x64.zip . It doesn't come with a SDL2_mixer import lib for me: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1C50YsS8JgX-et6UkjGLFL_fpDmH-pGtn/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @Hans Passant: Looking at the devel download, it does indeed provide the import lib. (However, not so the release package, where I would have expected it.) Thanks for the hint.

Comment: @Hans: You may want to post your comment regarding the \*devel\* download as answer, because I used the wrong package (not the devel one), which does not contain the import lib, while the devel one does. If you do, I can upvote your answer and mark it as solution.